# envers audit table name

Tags: java, hibernate-envers

I have kind of naive question related to envers. Can we name a audit table to something other then the default one, i.e., TableName_AUD and ya not just Prefix or suffix, full name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, if you annotate a given entity with `@AuditTable` you can specify the table that should be used. I don't think you can specify a global naming strategy to use.

Answer (score 3):

use configuration http://docs.jboss.org/envers/docs/index.html#configuration and you've got custom prefix or suffix for audited tables